# What does sharing refer to in the implementation of a functional programming language

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sharing

*Sharing* means that temporary data is stored if it is going to be used multiple times. That is, a function evaluates it's arguments only once. An example would be:

```
let x = sin x in x * x
```

What other features contribute to *sharing* and how would they interact with the need for practical programs to perform IO?

Comment: The caching of data for reuse is rather called "memoization", not "sharing". If you have tree-shaped data that contains the same subtree several times, then turning this into a directed acyclic graph (DAG) to "share" the common subtree; that is what I would call sharing. Besides, the question (due to its open-ended nature) does not quite fit the format of SO. Could you make it more concrete, give examples, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clearest example of sharing in functional programming comes from Clean, which is based on graph rewriting. There, a computation refers to a DAG, so we can view the expression `(sin x) * (sin x)` as

```
    (*)
  /     \
sin x   sin x
```

Graph rewriting systems have an explicit notion of sharing, so we could express that computation as

```
   (*)
   / \
   \ /
  sin x
```

pointing the multiplication node to the same node, thereby sharing the computation of `sin x`. Term rewriting systems do not have so explicit a notion of sharing, but the optimization is still relevant. In GHC, one can sometimes express sharing with local variables, e.g. rewriting

```
f x = (sin x) * (sin x)
```

into

```
f x = sinx * sinx
  where sinx = sin x
```

But since the two are semantically equivalent, the compiler is free to implement both the same way, with or without sharing. By my understanding, the GHC will generally preserve sharing introduced with local variables and sometimes introduce it (adding sharing to the first), but with no formal expression of sharing in term rewriting systems either behaviour is implementation dependent (see tel's comment and answer).

Sharing touches IO because side-effecting values cannot be shared. If we consider an impure language, there is a difference between

```
(string-append (read-line)
               (read-line))
```

and

```
(let ((s (read-line)))
  (string-append s s))
```

The first executes the IO action twice, requesting two lines from the user and appending them; the second "shares" the IO action, executing it once and appending it to itself. In general, sharing a pure computation reduces execution time without changing the result of the program, while sharing a side-effecting value (one that may change over time, or interacts with the user) changes the result. For the compiler to automatically share computations, it needs to know that they are pure, and thus that reducing the number of evaluations does not matter. Clean does this with uniqueness types; an IO action has the type attribute UNQ, which tells the compiler that it should not be shared. Haskell does the same somewhat differently with the IO monad.

Comment: Truly, there's no reason for your `where sinx = sin x` example to introduce sharing. Purity guarantees that whether or not the two values being multiplied are "pointer equal" the ultimate value of the expression is the same. Now, it's an obvious *optimization* to share that value and GHC does sometimes "float lets upward" to introduce this sharing. That said, we could also compute `sin x`, copy it to two addresses, then multiply if we want. Sharing is *unobservable* in the semantics of Haskell. `StableName` is the closest you can get without tying yourself to implementation details.

Comment: True (And now edited). I have seen that in general such a where clause will introduce sharing in GHC, but the flip side of being able to transparently share values is the ability to transparently unshare (inlining the `sin x`).

Comment: Yeah, agreed, GHC tends to do a good job finding sharing opportunities. `let` and `where` seem to guarantee it.

Answer (score 7):

Sharing is about a kind of equality: pointer equality. In Haskell's value land (semantic interpretation) there is no such thing as sharing. Values can only be equal if they have instances of `Eq` and then "equality" is defined to be the binary relation `(==)`.

Sharing thus escapes the semantic interpretation by referring to this underlying pointer equality which exists by virtue of implementation instead of semantics. This is a useful side effect sometimes, though. Unfortunately, since Haskell is defined by its semantic interpretation, use of sharing is undefined behavior. It's tied to a particular implementation. A few libraries use sharing and thus have behavior tied to GHC.

There is one built-in sharing mechanism, though. This is exposed by the [`StableName`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-Mem-StableName.html) interface. We generate `StableName a` objects using `makeStableName :: a -> IO (StableName a)` and have an `instance Eq (StableName a)`—thus `StableName` introduces some kind of equality for *any* type.

`StableName` equality is *almost* pointer equality. To quote the Haddock documentation

> If `sn1 :: StableName` and `sn2 :: StableName` and `sn1 == sn2` then `sn1` and `sn2` were created by calls to `makeStableName` on the same object.

Note that this is just an *if* statement, not an *if and only if*. The fact that two things can be "pointer equivalent" but still have different stable names sometimes is (a) forced by the flexibility Haskell leaves to the GC and (b) a loophole that allows `StableName`s to exist in any Haskell implementation even if there's no such thing as "pointer equality" in the implementation whatsoever.

These `StableName`s still have no semantic meaning, but since they're introduced in the `IO` monad that's "OK". Instead, they might be said to implement an (ironically) unstable subset of the smallest (most specific) equality relation possible on any type.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not an example of sharing -- it just multiplies a value with itself (and then throws the original value away).

Sharing is the case where some part of a data structure occurs twice in a larger data structure, or in different data structures. For example:

```
p  = (1, 2)
pp = (p, p)  -- p is shared between the first and second component of pp

xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = 0::1::xs
zs = 5::xs  -- ys and zs share the same tail
```

In memory, such sharing will result in a DAG structure.