# Haskell object lifetime performance

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc

```
foo x y = x*x + y

fat x y = let xx = x*x in xx + y

bar x = \y -> x*x + y

baz x = let xx = x*x in \y -> xx + y

foo' = foo 2

fat' = fat 2

bar' = bar 2

baz' = baz 2
```

Will repeated calling of `foo'`, `fat'`, `bar'`, or `baz'` result in different runtime performances? Basically, I am interested in how GHC will keep values around and when it relinquishes intermediate values. Would using a `where` clause result in different results if I replaced `let` with it?

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell this answer your question?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Ah, thanks. That basically covers it.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430376/what-does-sharing-refer-to-in-the-implementation-of-a-functional-programming-lan.